# unable to get data from iphone application

Tags: iphone

I have made a php web services that takes the username and password from iPhone application and saves the data in the users table.

I call that web service from my button touchup event like this:

```
 NSLog(userName.text);
 NSLog(password.text);

 NSString * dataTOB=[userName.text stringByAppendingString:password.text];

 NSLog(dataTOB);

 NSData * postData=[dataTOB dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding allowLossyConversion:YES];

 NSString *postLength = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d", [postData length]];

 NSLog(postLength);

 NSMutableURLRequest *request = [[[NSMutableURLRequest alloc] init] autorelease];

 NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"http://localhost:8888/write.php"]];

 [request setURL:url];
 [request setHTTPMethod:@"POST"];
 [request setValue:postLength forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Length"];
 [request setValue:@"application/x-www-form-urlencoded" forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Type"];
 [request setHTTPBody:postData];

 NSURLResponse *response;
 NSError *error;

 [NSURLConnection sendSynchronousRequest:request returningResponse:&response error:&error];

 if(error==nil)    
   NSLog(@"Error is nil");   
 else
   NSLog(@"Error is not nil");
 NSLog(@"success!");
```

I am getting nothing from Iphone side into the web service and I am unable to understand why this is happening. Although i debugged and found that everything is fine at the iphone application level but the call to the web service doesn't works as expected......

Please suggest.....

Thanks
Ashish

Answer (score 1):

Try logging localizedFailureReason or localizedRecoverySuggestion or localizedRecoveryOptions properties of 'error', if error is not nil. This may give you the reason if there is a failure encountered in sending the request or receiving the response.